# Alternative page title and meta data on login

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how to display alternative 'title' and other metadata on the login page.

Say I have a target URL say, https://example.com/thing/12345 ... if not logged in the user gets redirected to the login page, fine that's what I want, but on the login page I would like to inject the title, and maybe other metadata from the target page.

So that if a link such as above is shared in say Facebook, it will display the title/meta of the target URL and not the login URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per Laravel Documenation:

In your master template use `@yield('title')` to dynamically change the title

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>  //  add this code
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From your blade template use `@section('title')` to pass title to master layout

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title') // pass dynamic title from here

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

[Laravel -> Templates -> Blade Templating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating)

Comment: Not what I needed, but gave me an idea to set some session vars before I call return route('login') and use them in the template. So while not 100% for me, I'll 'accept' :)